# Qlikview, Using a CSV file to filter a field

Tags: excel, qlikview

In my dashboard, I would like for the user to have the option to filter a specific field by selecting an Execl/CSV file from their computer that has all the values for that field.

I am thinking that I can have a button that would prompt the user to select the file that contains all of these values. My problem is how would I have the dashboard read all these values and then filter the field that the values correspond to?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is - you can't

A bit of workaround is to to use the compound search to select multiple specified values in a field. For example if you have `Country` field which contains list of countries you can select more than one by start searching in the list box and paste the values you want to select in the following format: (Austria|Germany) In this case you should provide this list instead csv (if possible) and the user need to copy paste the search criteria.

Another possible solution is to have an Qlikview extension that can do the same for you. The extension will read the file and select the values.

**Update:**

Using the compound search and a bit of a variable logic might lead you to the same result. Please check [this post](https://community.qlik.com/message/1044555#1044555) for more info